# Is there an Octave equivalent of Matlab's `assessVariableEqual` function?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am looking for an Octave equivalent of Matlab Grader's [`assessVariableEqual`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlabgrader/ug/assessvariableequal.html) function that compares a variable with the expected value based on the data type, existence, and variable's value.

Is there a similar function in Octave?

Comment: I assume not because this comes from a educational package of MATLAB. However, this simply uses a combination of `exists()` `class()` `isequal()` and just value comparison, I am sure you can write your own with your specs in few lines using those

Comment: Now, if you are not preparing educational material to mark students, this is probably not the function you are looking for, for whatever thing you want to do.

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri. Thank you for your help. Yes, it comes from Matlab Grader; I should have included it in my question.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I am actually converting educational material from Matlab to Octave, so this is why this function would come in handy :)